# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. - Esri Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm working on this project and I'm getting this error. I haven't found a solution that fits my code. The error =

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

and it also asks me to

> Check the render method of App.

Here is my code.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import L from 'leaflet';
import * as ELG from 'esri-leaflet-geocoder';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';



 class App extends React.Component {
  
    componentDidMount() {
      const map = this.leafletMap.leafletElement;
      const searchControl = new ELG.Geosearch().addTo(map);
      const results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
  
      searchControl.on("results", function(data) {
        results.clearLayers();
        for (let i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
        }
      });
    }
   
  render() {
    const center = [37.7833, -122.4167];
    return (
      <Map
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
        center={center}
        zoom="10"
        ref={m => {
          this.leafletMap = m;
        }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&copy; <a href='https://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url={"http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
        />
        <div className="pointer" />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

  




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at React Leaflet documentation there seems to be no `Map` component. Meaning that the value of `Map` in your code is set to `undefined` which results in the error you receive.

Change `Map` into [`MapContainer`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#mapcontainer) and you should be good to go.

The React Leaflet project probably choose this name to not conflict with the JavaScript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class.

Comment: Thank you that worked really well but now that i've used map container I have a new error that says _Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined_ and the only solution I found was people recommending not using react-leaflet as it is too old. Do you know of any solution.

Comment: @kboy I'm not sure if the `ref` property woks for the `MapContainer`, since there is nothing documented about it. It does support the `whenCreated` property, which accepts a callback that is passed the map. Try using `whenCreated={map => this.initializeMap(map)}` and rename the `componentDidMount` method into `initializeMap` (or another name of your choice), which accepts the map through its parameter.